# Android WebView Javascript Issue

Tags: javascript, android, webview, scroll

I'm quite new of Android and during the development of one app, I have encountered the following issue:

I'm using a WebView inside my app for viewing web sites (it does not matter what kind of site, can be Google or Reddit or anything else). I know I can use a "browser Intent" with **Intent.ACTION_VIEW** but for the purpose of my App I must use a WebView.

So, I have enabled javascript and DOM api storage with:

```
getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

My problem comes after that the page has finished loading and some Javascript automatically starts. Basically if the user has already scroll down and the Javascript tells the page to hide/show some content (example a DIV) the scroll resets to top.

My question is:
how can I avoid this behavior? I want that the Javascript loads correctly but it does not interfere with the user's navigation. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance,
Best A.

Comment: Please provide code snippet so that we can help you better.

Comment: @androiduser Not sure what kind of code snippet I should provide. I just do a normal call to webview.loadUrl(myurl);

Comment: Call webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); and
      webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); before you call loadurl

Comment: I did it. I also have onPageStarted and onPageFinished. I have put some "Toasts" inside and I have noticed that the Javascript starts at the end of onPageFinished.